# Votei 40 vezes hoje, mas não recebi medalha Vox Populi

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, medalhas

Hoje decidi obter essa medalha, durante o caminho consegui a sufrágio, porém quando cheguei aos 40 votos a medalha Vox Populi ainda não me foi concebida,
dei uma olhada no perfil de outros usuários, e notei que a maioria recebia esta junto a sufrágio, ocorreu algo ou essa só é garantida no fim do dia?

Edit: coincidentemente acabei de receber a medalha, não sei se foi um moderador que verificou, e se essa pergunta é pertinente ainda

Comment: Você retirou algum dos votos que deu? É que isso faz com que não se chegue aos 40 votos num dia.

Comment: talvez isso tenha acontecido mesmo, porque tentei votar de novo e logo recebi a medalha

Answer (score 20):

## Tenha paciência, jovem.

Algumas medalhas normalmente são computadas em determinados horários do dia. Tenha paciência que logo ela aparecerá para você.

Comment: Bela virtude, mas incompatível com o século XXI... :)